# How to adapt the following data transformation from pyspark to scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Doing the following transformation in pyspark.how can I adapt in to scala?

```
accept_value= when(col("column1") < 0.9, 1).otherwise(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can write something like this in **scala**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,when}
val accept_value = df.withColumn("converted_value", when(col("number").lt(0.9), 1).otherwise(0))
```

**pyspark** for reference:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
accept_value = df.withColumn("converted_value",when(col("number") < 0.9, 1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Great answer. Could you edit the question to include the necessary `import`s? This would help others adapting their pyspark code to scala.

Comment: thanks!.. sure will update my answer with necessary **import**